# Do all compact manifolds have finite volume?

Tags: manifolds, volume

Let $M$ be a compact $k$-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Does $M$ being compact imply that the $k$-dimensional volume of $\operatorname{vol}_{k}(M)$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, use the Hopf-Rinow theorem to bound $\operatorname{vol}_k(M)$ by an integral of a bounded continuous function on a compact subset of a tangent space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: any compact manifold $M$ has finite volume with respect to any Riemannian metric.  Given any point $p\in M$, we can find a bounded coordinate chart around $p$ on which each component of the metric is bounded, so that coordinate chart will have finite volume.  Since $M$ is compact, it is covered by finitely many of these finite-volume coordinate charts, and so $M$ has finite volume.

Comment: Can you clarify something for me? Why can we find a bounded coordinate chart around $p$? And why does every component of metric $g=(g_{ij})$ is bounded, actually what does this line mean exactly?

Comment: It's more generally true that any continuous function on a compact manifold has finite volume. Since it is continuous, it's bounded. As Eric explained, finite charts are enough where any chart can be chosen to have finite volume. You can then compute the integral in the charts and use the boundedness of f.