# Finite volume conditions of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990455/do-all-compact-manifolds-have-finite-volume) and wondering if there are more general results answering the question "Under which condition do manifolds have to have a finite riemannian volume?". I know that bounded balls can have infinite volume even [in a riemannian setting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994809/do-balls-of-finite-radius-have-finite-volume?rq=1).

I would appreciate any hints and result!

Comment: I quite don't understand the question: could you be more precise on what you mean by "have to have a finite measure"?

Comment: I replaced it with "riemannian volume" to be more precise.

Comment: Every noncompact manifold admits a metric with infinite volumn.

Comment: I guess you can do that by increasing the curvature to infinity in a fitting way? So approaching my question with that in mind a simple result be bounding the curvature and the manifold, but that would be a minimal result i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Myers' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem) gives a sufficient condition: any complete Riemannian manifold whose Ricci curvature is bounded below by a positive constant is compact, and thus has finite volume.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bishop-Gromov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality) states that any finite-radius metric ball on which the Ricci curvature is bounded below, even by a negative constant, has finite volume. So a sufficient condition would be bounded + Ricci curvature bounded below. This still isn't a sufficient condition; there's unbounded manifolds with finite volume.